# Vivado HLS implementation of RISCV

Tags: c++

I am facing following error in this code. Its an implementation of RISCV in vivado HLS. Is it the wrong way to write in binary in this format? These warning are repeated in every line. How can i remove this error?

> Error: missing terminating ' character   func imm_u return
>   {inst[31:12],12'0b0};
>                                      ^

```
#include "const.h"
#include "modules.h"

module rvdec{
  func set any {
    inst[6:0]== OP_IMM:      imm();
    inst[6:0]== OP_LUI:      lui();
    inst[6:0]== OP_AUIPC:    auipc();
    inst[6:0]== OP_RTYPE:    rtype();
    inst[6:0]== OP_JAL:      jal();
    inst[6:0]== OP_JALR:     jalr();
    inst[6:0]== OP_BRANCH:   branch();
    inst[6:0]== OP_LOAD:     load();
    inst[6:0]== OP_STORE:    store();
    inst[6:0]== OP_MISC_MEM: misc_mem();
    inst[6:0]== OP_SYSTEM:   sys();
  }
  func imm_i return 32#inst[31:20];
  func imm_s return 32#{inst[31:25],inst[11:8]};
  func imm_b return 32#{inst[31],inst[7],inst[30:25],inst[11:8],0b0};
  func imm_u return {inst[31:12],12'0b0};
  func imm_j return 32#{inst[31],inst[19:12], inst[20],
                inst[30:25], inst[24:21],0b0};

}

module rvgpr {
  integer i;
  mem dat[32][32];
  func rs1 {
    if(adr1==0) return 32'0b0;
    generate(i=1; i<32; i++)
      if(adr1==i) return dat[i];
  }
  func rs2 {
    if(adr2==0) return 32'0b0;
    generate(i=1; i<32; i++)
      if(adr2==i) return dat[i];
  }
  func write dat[wadr]:=wdat;
}

module add32 {
  func exec {
    wire i[33];
    i=33'a+33'b+33'cin;
    cout=i[32];
    return i[31:0];
  }
}

module sft32 {
  wire sr[32],sgn[32];
  func_self sr_int(sr);
  integer i;
  variable va[32];
  variable vs[32];
  func sr_int {
    va=a;
    generate(i=0; i<5; i++){
      if(sft[i]){
    va = va >> (1<<i);
    vs =  {(1<<i)'0b1,(32-(1<<i))'0b0} |(vs>>(1<<i));
      }
    }
    sr=va;
    sgn=vs;
  }
  func srl { sr_int(); return sr;}
  func sra { sr_int(); return sr|sgn;}
  func sll {
    va=a;
    generate(i=0; i<5; i++)
      va = if(sft[i]) va << (1<<i) else va;
    return va;
  }
}

module rvalu {
  add32 add;
  sft32 sft;
  func exec any {
    sel==ALU_ADD: return add.exec(a,b,0b0);
    sel==ALU_SUB: return add.exec(a,~b,0b1);
    sel==ALU_SLL: return sft.sll(a,b[4:0]);
    sel==ALU_SLT: return
                    32'((a[31]&~b[31])
            |(add.exec(a,~b,0b1)[31]&~a[31]&~b[31])
            |(add.o[31]&a[31]&b[31])); 
    sel==ALU_SLTU: return 32'(add.exec(a,~b,0b1)[15]);
    sel==ALU_XOR: return a^b;
    sel==ALU_SRL: return sft.srl(a,b[4:0]);
    sel==ALU_SRA: return sft.sra(a,b[4:0]);
    sel==ALU_OR : return a|b;
    sel==ALU_AND: return a&b;
  }
}

module rvcmp {
  add32 add;
  wire reseq,reslt,resltu;
  func_self eq():reseq;
  func_self lt():reslt;
  func_self ltu():resltu;
```

Comment: Doesn't look like C++ to me. And while macro's can make C++ unrecognisable, the `6:0` isn't legal in C++ by any interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

This code looks like System Verilog.  Try running it in Vivado instead of Vivado HLS.